# Transferring rows between tables from different databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have 2 mysql databases, which have the same structure, but are from two different sites hosted on 2 different servers.

I would like to be able to select just some specific rows from table A(db 1), save them to my computer and then insert them into table A(db 2), which already has its own content which I would like to also keep in the db.

Until now I have tried to do this:
I have selected and exported them to my computer, but when I try to insert them into table A (db2) I get an error message #1050 - Table 'A' already exists.

I don't want to replace the table A (db 2), I just want to add to it some info from table A (db 1), but also to keep the existing data.

How do I achieve this from the database side?

Comment: Removed the sql-server tag because the question is explicitly about MySQL.

Comment: Can you show us the commands you are trying to run.

Comment: export how? as dumps? dump with the `--skip-create-table` (or whatever the option is) so you get ONLY the `insert` queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `mysqldump` to dump the database, use the `--no-create-info` option to prevent it from putting `CREATE TABLE` statements in the dump file.

Comment: I am logged into the database server in my cpanel, I have selected them mannualy, then click export as .sql file, and download into my computer.  Then I am importing the .sql files from my computer to the second database, but I don't see any --no-create-info option anywhere.

Comment: I don't know cpanel, I don't know if it has an equivalent option. But you can probably load the `.sql` file into a text editor and remove the `CREATE TABLE` command from it.

Comment: Many Thanks! I have removed the CREATE TABLE command and it worked! Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I would just `select columns_you_want` from table A

Then I would use vim or (preferably) sed to format the results so that

```
name: 'smith'
country: 'usa'
```

becomes transformed into `insert into tableB(name,country) values ('smith','usa')'`